# Как вывести все поля из Lead при работе с amocrm.v2?

Tags: python-3.x, amocrm

Пишу код на языке `python3` и использую библиотеку `amocrm.v2`. Я пытаюсь вывести все поля из `Lead` но некоторые объекты имеют странные значения. Вот пример:

```
today = datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
tasks = Lead.objects.all()

current = datetime.today().date()

n = 0

for task in tasks:
    if str(task.created_at.date()) == '2023-04-21':

        n += 1

        print(n, task, task.name)
```

Вывод:

```
Lead(account_id = 30852334, 
closed_at = None, 
closest_task_at = 2023-04-21 05:36:16, 
contacts = <amocrm.v2.fields._ListData object at 0x10c302f10>, 
created_at = 2023-04-21 05:31:15, 
group_id = 0, 
id = 8659237, is_deleted = False, loss_reason = [], loss_reason_id = None, 
name = Заявка от (Алексей — Виза в Болгарию Австрию), 
None = <class 'amocrm.v2.entity.note.NotesField.on_get_instance.<locals>.Note'>, 
price = 0, score = None, updated_at = 2023-04-21 05:31:17)
```

Пытался создать `class`, но ничего хорошего из этого не вышло, не могу понять как вывести все значения в нормальном виде, если у кого то есть идеи как это реализовать то буду очень рад.

Comment: Что здесь странного? Что такое «в нормальном виде»?

Comment: @andreymal вот например: contacts = <amocrm.v2.fields._ListData object at 0x10c302f10>

Comment: Не знаю, почему нет толковой документации, но получается, что лучшая документация — это код, и если заглянуть в [код класса _ListData](https://github.com/Krukov/amocrm_api/blob/c9d64b1395f58374aa3213bb8959fa884a2e82bf/amocrm/v2/fields.py#L129-L138), то можно увидеть, что его можно запихнуть в цикл для получения элементов

Comment: @andreymal, добавил в код class, но вывод остался таким же, можете отправить пример как вывести итоговый результат в нормальном виде